# Why isn't this PHP snippet working?

Tags: php

In localhost (using Wamp on windows). I'm trying to use this:

```
<?
$xml = simplexml_load_file(‘http://stocklamp.tumblr.com/api/read/xml’);
$posts = $xml->xpath(“/tumblr/posts/post[@type=’regular’]”);
foreach($posts as $post) {?>  
<?echo $post[‘id’];?>
<?echo $post[‘url-with-slug’];?>”>
<?echo $post->{‘regular-title’};?>
<?echo $post->{‘regular-body’};?>
<?echo date(“jS D M, H:i”,strtotime($post[‘date’]));?>
<?}?>
```

<s>When trying, all I see is this on my site:</s>

```
xpath(“/tumblr/posts/post[@type=’regular’]”); foreach($posts as $post) { ?> ”> {‘regular-title’};?> {‘regular-body’};?>
```

I found the snippet here:

http://stocklamp.tumblr.com/post/274675902/putting-your-tumblr-posts-on-your-websites-the-easy-way

<s>Edit: fixed. Now I'm getting</s>

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in
>   C:\wamp\www..\index.php on line 52

and it is this line:

> $xml =
>   simplexml_load_file(‘http://stocklamp.tumblr.com/api/read/xml’);

I keep getting this error: http://codepad.org/7f1IejIG

Okay. Now I go that fixed, but how do I get the posts by tag?

changing 'type=...' doesn't work.

```
$posts = $xml->xpath("/tumblr/posts/post[@type='file']");
```

Comment: Does your server support [PHP short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)? Or have actual PHP support at all?

Comment: This is happening on localhost.

Comment: Please see: http://codepad.org/fum4lWon If this were being parsed by PHP, it would throw an error. Are you seeing an error? If not, your page is not being processed by PHP (and see Cyclone's answer).

Comment: See AlienWebGuy's answer for the parse error.

Comment: ... and don't use short tags; use `<?php` instead.

Comment: The error shown on that codepad link have to do with security settings; codepad (and Ideone) do not allow you to access external content, and so disable certain functions and activities. If you are getting this on your Wamp localhost, it probably means your firewall is blocking access to the internet to your Apache server on your computer, or some other thing.

Comment: Select an answer to this question and open a new question with your latest edit. :) See my comment on my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last problem is to resolve is that the API XML url provided on the blog is not right. The following works:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://stocklamp.tumblr.com/api/read/'); // No /xml
$posts = $xml->xpath('/tumblr/posts/post[@type="regular"]');
foreach($posts as $post) {?>  
<?echo $post['id'];?>
<?echo $post['url-with-slug'];?>”>
<?echo $post->{'regular-title'};?>
<?echo $post->{'regular-body'};?>
<?echo date("jS D M, H:i",strtotime($post['date']));?>
<?}?>
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/tumblrtest.php

**EDIT**

Try running this code without the tags interspersed:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://stocklamp.tumblr.com/api/read/'); // No /xml
$posts = $xml->xpath('/tumblr/posts/post[@type="regular"]');
foreach($posts as $post) {  
    echo $post['id'];
    echo $post['url-with-slug'];
    echo $post->{'regular-title'};
    echo $post->{'regular-body'};
    echo date("jS D M, H:i",strtotime($post['date']));
}
?>
```

Comment: i keep getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\jessblum-proj\index.php on line 62

Comment: Not sure why that would give you that error. My suggestion would be to get a professionally managed PHP-based site. You can try putting the closing `?>` on the next line, see if that works. But your code should work, as I demonstrated.

Comment: tried it on a page with no html. just php. keeps giving me error of the last line.

Comment: See my edit. I believe that CodePad and other post-your-own code sites block certain functions, which is why you see that particular error (Ideone shows the same error). That particular error says essentially "warning, you can't get that external file, and likewise the resulting object is not usable".

Comment: And I added a comment about that. This is the neverending question; at some point you will need to select a correct answer and open a new question for your other issues. This is a question/answer site, not a support forum. It's been proven that the code snippet works with adjustments, so this question should have an answer selected (by checking a checkmark) and move on. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your page isn't running as PHP. If you view source, you'll see the entire PHP code visible on your page as plain HTML.

The bit that displays is after the $xml-> bit, because it thinks the opening php tag and the -> are one big html tag.

Is the file extension .php? What's the file name? Where did you put this code? Try replacing `<?` with `<?php`, sometimes web servers don't have short tags enabled.

Comment: extension. haha wow. feel soo dumb. now i have another problem.

Comment: For your second problem, take a look at AlienWebguy's answer (the curly quotes)

Answer (score 2):

You are using curly quotes. Try this:

```
<?
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://stocklamp.tumblr.com/api/read');
    $posts = $xml->xpath("/tumblr/posts/post[@type='regular']");
    foreach($posts as $post) {  
    echo $post['id'];
    echo $post['url-with-slug'];
    echo $post->{'regular-title'};
    echo $post->{'regular-body'};
    echo date("jS D M, H:i",strtotime($post['date']));
    }
?>
```

Comment: Curly quotes or not, the php code would throw a syntax error. This PHP simply isn't being executed

Comment: You copied in the curly quotes :)  http://codepad.org/NfjO7wYU  -- The error on codepad is because they likely have simplexml_load_file blocked for security reasons.

Comment: We're trying to show you that curly quotes are not the cause of this particular error

Comment: @AlienWebguy - Yes, I know. The purpose was that without the error, it wasn't being parsed. I think the OP has several problems going on here, mainly that the OP does not know what they are doing. :)

Comment: yeah thats kinda true jared. hehe.

Comment: And that was a good catch on the curly quotes, I didn't notice them until you pointed them out.

Comment: Ignorance can be overcome, at least he realized he had a problem and came here, which is better than flailing around in the dark.

Comment: I'm still getting that damn error though. parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Comment: What are you editing the page with? Try plain notepad to replace the single and double quotes. Do NOT use Word or Word Pad or any regular document editing program.

Comment: lol, I'm not that much of a noob. trust me. I just not that good with php and i'm trying to get this finish to fast. i'm using e. plain code editor.

Comment: Well, I hope you're not getting the same exact error; it should be some warnings and a Fatal Error concerning the fact that this url: http://stocklamp.tumblr.com/api/read/xml is not XML, but a JSON object.

Comment: Now, maybe ironically, if you take the `/xml` off, you get an XML file that works. See: http://jfcoder.com/test/tumblrtest.php